# Prove $f(x) = a_n x^n + ...+a_0$ has at most $n$ roots.

Tags: calculus

I took this question from Serge Lang's "A First Course in Calculus". Any input in verifying my attempt is much appreciated.

The question is actually broken into two parts:

(1) Let $f$ be a function which is infinitely differentiable. Let $c_1 < c_2 <... <c_r$ be numbers such that $f(c_i) = 0 $ for all $i$. Show that $f'$ has at least $r-1$ zeros.

(2) Apply the preceding exercise to a polynomial $f(x) = a_n x^n + ... + a_0$ where $a_n \ne 0$ and $a_i$'s are numbers. Conclude that such a polynomial has at most $n$ roots.

Here is my take at the solution:

For (1), by applying Rolle's Theorem $r-1$ times then we solve it. As for (2), I feel like trying to do a direct proof is very difficult. As such I attempt an indirect proof. Following is the attempt:

We first define the set $C := \{x | f(x) = 0 \}$ to be the roots of the n-degree polynomial. We want to prove that $|C| \le n$. Now assume by contradiction that $|C| > n$. Without loss of generality we can let $|C|$ be $n+1$. If we differentiate $f(x)$ $n$ times, we have $f^{(n)} (x) = n! \cdotp a_n$. Note this $n$-th derivative is a non-zero constant function. Since we assume that the polynomial has $n+1$ roots, it follows that $f^{(n)}$ has at least one root, from part (1) of this exercise. However this is  a contradiction, since $f^{(n)} (x) \ne 0$ for all $x$. Now let $|C|$ be any other number greater than $n$. We will arrive at the same conclusion that $f^{(n)}$ has at least one root which contradicts that $f^{(n)} (x)$ has no roots.  $\Box$

Comment: Proof looks good, and it can be easily rephrased as a direct proof by induction on the degree $n$ of the polynomial. $f'$ has degree $n-1$ so if (by the induction hypothesis) $f'$ has at most $n-1$ roots, then it follows that $f$ has at most $n$ roots.

Comment: @dxiv thank you for the input.

Comment: I am curious how one solves (2) using (1). How are roots of multiplicity $>1$ handled?

Comment: @copper.hat $r$ from $c_r$ can be strictly lower than $n$ from $x^n$. So by (1) it's still true that $f$ has at most $1$ more (real) root than $f'$. At least that was my reading of the question.

Comment: @dxiv: That is how I would have read it, but I don't have Serge's book to see if he considers multiplicity when counting zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, From the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), we know that the polynomial has at least one complex root such as $z$. Hence, it is divisible by $(x-z)$ which gives you a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Then by induction you can apply the same argument on the reduced-degree polynomial.